# Can you use characters such as ( and ) in Nlog target filename for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

For example ...

C:_Logs\UAT (Testing)\DebugService_${shortdate}.log

... does not work and writes a file named UAT (Testing)

C:_Logs\UATTesting\DebugService_${shortdate}.log

... does work and writes a file named DebugService_Date.log to the correct path.

Comment: Have you checked the NLog Internal Logger to see how it parses the input? It will show the parsed layout and the filenames being created. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/285

Answer (score 0):

Yes, special characters are supported.

Also there is an unit test that tests the specials characters, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2714